# Google Analytics Custom Tracking

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

For marketing purposes, if a link to our company website is posted on a page on an external website. Is it possible to track the time in which the user landed on the external website and clicked on the link to our company website, using custom tracking ?

I have been reading about custom GA tags however am having a hard time understanding how to make the above possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot track an external website, as you can only track sites where you control the tracking code.

If you have control over the external site and have implemented analytics tracking there you would

- create a timestamp on page load
- add an onclick event handler to the link to your site
- in the callback function for that link create another timestamp, substract the original timestamp to get a duration
- send a user timing call:

  ga('send', 'timing', 'Link', 'Duration to click', duration);

Where the "duration" parameter would be replaced with your timestamp.

As I've said that would only work if you can run your own Google Analytics on the external site which does not seems very likely. Plus I have really no idea what you mean by "custom GA tags" (there are custom variables and custom dimensions/metrics, both of which will not help you here).

So basically the anwser is you can't, really.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is an option in Google for custom HTML tag tracking, where you provide your HTML and JavaScript code by copying and pasting it in to an input box. It is located on the Google Analytics settings landing page its on New->Tag->Custom Tag

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about Google Analytics ? Because there is certainly no way to enter custom code into Google Analytics (and how would it help to track external sites if there was ?). I'm reasonanly sure your are confusing something, and if not I would be eager to learn something new, so either way it would be cool if you could include a screenshot into your question (as it would help to see what it was that you have tried).